# Using Rally.ui.AddNew with details

Tags: rally

I've created a Rally.ui.AddNew button to add a new release.

If the user hits "Add with Details" (which is the only active button for releases, you can't add a release without details) I would like certain fields to be set by default when the dialog is opened.

For example, I would like the "Create matching Releases in all child projects" checkbox to be set (if it exists), and I'd like to put a default note in the "Notes" area.

How do I do that?  It does not look like the listeners "beforecreate" or "create" are called if the details dialog comes up.

Ideally I'd also like a chance to check these items again with another listener just before the item is created.  Do these listeners exist?

Answer (score 0):

The Rally standard editor likely provides only limited capabilities for defaulting field values when instantiated. As an indication, AppSDK1 had the [rally.sdk.util.Navigation.popupCreatePage()](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/navigation) method, which would accept an object with default values, for example:

```
   // Open Defect editor with Defect default-associated to User Story with OID 12345
   rally.sdk.util.Navigation.popupCreatePage("defect", {requirementOid: 12345});
```

The default key/value pairs that this method accepts were not well-documented. One of Rally's UI Engineers provided me with this list at one time:

```
rally.sdk.util.Navigation.popupCreatePage defaults keys
User Story:
defaultName
rank
iteration
release
parent
dpyOid {dependency}

Defect:
defaultName
defectSuiteOid {Defect Suites}
testCaseResult
testCase
requirement
iteration

Defect Suite:
defaultName
rank
iteration

Portfolio Item:
defaultName
rank
parent

Task:
workProduct

Test Case:
testfolderOid {Test Folder}
artifactOid {Artifact}

Test Set:
iteration
release
```

While the above list may not be exhaustive (or even completely accurate anymore), it suggests that the allowed defaults for the standard Rally Editor may not include the "Create matching Releases in all child projects" checkbox or the Notes field.

Nonetheless, it's not immediately apparent to me that there is any method or config for AppSDK2's [Rally.ui.AddNew](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.AddNew) that is an analog in functionality to AppSDK1's rally.sdk.util.Navigation.popupCreatePage() ability to setup default values into the resulting Editor window. Hopefully one of Rally's UI Engineers may have better information to add to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for now not all the built-in fields are defaultable (see Mark W's answer above for the list of pre-fillable fields).  Any custom fields are though.  You'll want to check out the [beforeeditorshow](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.AddNew-event-beforeeditorshow) event.  You can modify the params there.

```
addNewComponent.on('beforeeditorshow', function(addNew, params) {
    params.defaultName = 'foo';
    params.c_MyField = 'bar';
});
```

Note that if you would just like to create or edit objects you can directly call the methods on [Rally.nav.Manager](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.nav.Manager).